# Remove Time portion from DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have DTO object.From there i need to remove Time portion from date time,But my NewsDateOnly also consist of time portion

I have seen some duplicates but all those things convert that to the String .

```
public DateTime NewsDate { get; set; }

public DateTime NewsDateOnly
{
    get 
    {
        return NewsDate.Date;
    }
}
```

Comment: ToShortDateString(); won't do you?

Comment: `.ToShortDateString()` or `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` if you need Date in string format. but if you need **Only** date in `DateTime` type then `.Date` in will add `12:00:00 AM` as a default time value to it